# How to monitor Executors or other Task Executing Threads in Spring MVC

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-mvc, executorservice

I am creating a web application and in this I will be creating many services and executors to do some tasks.I have extended dispacter servlet and started executors or other threads in init method.Is this the right approach?

Now Suppose if any request comes and that executor or similar task executing thread dies after throwing Exception.

1.I suppose that it will affect other requests also.So what shall I do in such cases?

2.How can I create a monitor thread which will check if all critial tasks executing thread and executors are properly running?

3.Should I keep another backup executor prepared and deferred to takeover the failed executor in such situations?If so then how?

Comment: If the Question is unclear ,then please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

It is an old one, but maybe it would help someone :)

For ExecutorService there is a nice example on how to approach the problem in Codahale Metrics: https://github.com/dropwizard/metrics/blob/master/metrics-core/src/main/java/com/codahale/metrics/InstrumentedExecutorService.java

I did not find anything as good for the Spring AsyncTaskExecutors :/

Answer (score 0):

Its been a while since I have used an Executor, are you using one of the built-in executors from Java, Spring, or are you rolling your own?  Spring has a bunch, and I think Java gives you two or three concrete implementations.

Anyhow, I think the answer would be to roll some sort of monitoring service, like maybe something using JMX if you have that available.  If you wanted to wire your Executors auto-magically you could use the [ApplicationContextAware](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.6.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextAware.html) interface to get a reference to the [ApplicationContext](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.6.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext.html), which has a method called [getBeansOfType()](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.6.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/ListableBeanFactory.html#getBeansOfType%28java.lang.Class,%20boolean,%20boolean%29).  If you want to take the more straight-forward approach, then you can simply write your monitoring service to inject the executors in there directly.

Another option would be to get an external monitoring framework/app.  Something like Dynatrace, which attaches to the JVM process and monitors things or, if you don't mind switching app servers, SpringSource's tcServer, which has optional instrumented Spring JARs  and provides a ton of out-of-the-box monitoring.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Well you have said a lot in your answer.Let me read what you have said.Give me sometime to check and I will come back to you.